# adjusting position of dialog box in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $("<div></div>").addClass("dialog").attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id")).appendTo("body").dialog({
        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
        minWidth: 500,
        minHeight: 100,
        resizable: false,

        close: function () {
          $(this).remove()
        },

        modal: true
      }).load(this.href);
    });

    $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
    });

    $(".refresh").live("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      location.reload();
    });
  });
</script>
```

i am using above jquery to get dialog box. but when the dialog box is shown it appears in the random part of the window which is very uncomforting. I want to make the dialog box appear in the center of the window. What should I do to make dialog box appear in center of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jQueryUI dialog documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/):

> position
>
> ```
> String, Array Default:
> "center"
> ```
>
> Specifies where the dialog should be displayed. Possible values:
>
> 1) a
>   single string representing position within viewport: 'center', 'left',
>   'right', 'top', 'bottom'.
>
> 2) an array containing an x,y coordinate
>   pair in pixel offset from left, top corner of viewport (e.g.
>   [350,100])
>
> 3) an array containing x,y position string values (e.g.
>   ['right','top'] for top right corner). Code examples
>
> Initialize a dialog with the position option specified.
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).dialog({ position: "top" });
> ```
>
> Get or set the position option, after init.
>
> ```
> //getter
> var position = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position" );
> //setter
> $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", "top" );
> ```

So have you tried the variant with the exact position?

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position", "[350, 100]" );
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried

```
 $(".dialog").dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
```

or

```
.dialog({
         title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
         minWidth: 500,
         minHeight: 100,
         resizable: false,                      
         close: function () { $(this).remove() },
         position:'center',
         modal: true
       })
```

Comment: That should be the default setting: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-position

Comment: well in this case may be your other css creating problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this CSS to dialog box:

```
​.dialog {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px; /* -width/2 */
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px; /* -height/2 */
    background-color: red;
}​
```

And I suggest this JS:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".openDialog").on("click", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();

         $("<div/>",{
             class: "dialog",
             id: $(this).attr("data-dialog-id")
         }).appendTo("body");
         .dialog({
            title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
            minWidth: 500,
            minHeight: 100,
            resizable: false,                      
            close: function () { $(this).remove() },
            modal: true
         })
         .load(this.href);
     });

     $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         //$(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
     });

     $(".refresh").live("click", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         location.reload();
     });
 }); ​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MFPpw/